# Git does not recognize new folder adds and its sub directories

Tags: git, directory, push, addition, commit

I have:

```
dirA/dir1
dirA/dir2
```

`dirA` has been added and I see it on the browser - when I click "`dirA`", I see `dir1` and `dir2`, grayed out like I have explained below.
`dir1` and `dir2`, both have more than one sub-directories and files.

```
git add dir1
git commit -m "..."
```

I get a message "`On branch master, nothing to commit, working directory clean`"

I am not sure why it wont go through and I see those as "grayed out" on the GitHub repo via browser.

Can someone help? I saw some similar threads on stackoverflow but they did not help me.

Comment: I did and I get the same response as above on doing a "git commit".

Comment: is dirA your Git Repository ?

Comment: there is an existing repo where I created a folder called "dirA". I am also migrating from hg to github here.

Comment: then just add dirA to your repo and all the sub-directories and files will be added. If you did this and git says "On branch master, nothing to commit, working directory clean", then you have already commited your code. Maybe try to push your commit to see it on your github server.

Comment: should i have "git push reponame"? where the reponame is the name of your https://....?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your question. Maybe you should take a look again on how to use GIT. On the GIT website you can find a really good book (http://git-scm.com/book) which helps you to understand how to use GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see on GitHub "grayed" folder, followed by a SHA1, those are [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

See "[Git submodules in github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300781/6309)"

[image: GitHub submodules]

That means they are nested git sub-repos which are referenced by the main repo.