# How can I use a git repository in my parent git project?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I tried using submodules to keep a copy from github repository inside my 3rd party directory. After creating and fetching the files, when I commit from project it only see the folder, no the files (and yes, the files are there).

Is there a specific command?

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, you will only see a **[gray folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25479758/6309)**: it is the [gitlink special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309), recording the SHA1 of said submodule.

On your local clone, as long as you do a

```
git submodule update --init
```

You will see the full content of the submodule.

But when you push, yuo must push from:

- the submodule folder, in order for the submodule upstream repo to record your new commit
- go back to the parent repo (`cd ..`), add, commit and push the new gitlink state (which records the new SHA1 of your submodule): that is what updates the "gray folder" in your GitHub repo when you push from your local clone.