# Cannot open git submodule folder on GitHub online

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I recently added [this](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/noetic-devel) github repo as a submodule in my project repo. I cannot open the root folder of the repo in my project repo [here](https://github.com/WaliaRohan/TurtlebotNavigation/tree/main/catkin_ws/src). I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300781/13784106) answer and it says that both the name and the commit hash should appear as links but that does not seem to be the case for me. I directly cloned the submodule repo into my project, so I had to first do `git rm --cached catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/` and then execute `git submodule add https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/noetic-devel catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/` to add the submodule. This is my first time using submodules and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Looking for any kind of hints on what I did wrong and what is the correct way to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/noetic-devel is not a repository and hence cannot be added as a submodule. It's a branch `noetic-devel` inside repo https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations. To fix your problem remove the wrong submodule and re-add the correct one:

```
git submodule deinit -f -- catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/
git rm --cached catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/
git submodule add -b noetic-devel https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/
```

Comment: Thanks. I additionally had to delete the entire sub module folder from my local repository before running the first command. After doing that, I ran the first and second commands, re-cloned the submodule repo and then executed command 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers